Extract geometry information from a .shp file without the associated files
A client sent me a shapefile: C:\example.shp Of course they forgot the .shx, .dbf, .prj, .etc. All I really care about is the geometry and I know that it is stored in the .shp. Is there a way to extract that without the associated files?
Additional Info: I'm comfortable with python and QGIS but mostly work in an ESRI environment. I saw this question: Which Shapefile parts are necessary to convert to geojson? and this comment: 
but I'm not familiar with the process described.

Is it really GIS data if you don't care about the feature attributes? I suggest you educate the user about the nature of data, and ask them for a complete dataset.

Of course educating folks on GIS is important, but some clients can be frustrating enough that asking for help on stack exchange and being willing to learn a whole new tool can seem like the easier route, even if only momentarily.

It's not an answer but if recreating those files would solve your actual problem, consider the answers on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131132/creating-missing-dbf-file-for-shapefile

You can recreate the missing .shx sidecar file using the processing algorithm "Repair Shapefile" which is part of the Processing toolbox of QGIS. Then you will be able to open the repaired ESRI Shapefile layer in QGIS.
Alternatively, you can also use the "ogr2ogr" program of the GDAL/OGR library:
ogr2ogr C:\repaired.shp C:\example.shp --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX=YES


This worked for me. Additional info for ESRI folks - to get the shapefile back to an ESRI environment, simply export it to a new shapefile from QGIS, and it will get a .dbf, .cpg, and .qmd file as well. You can also define a projection on the way out to get your .prj file, if you know the projection.
